# Regex to return all characters until "/" searching backwards

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm having trouble with this regex and I think I'm almost there.

```
m =re.findall('[a-z]{6}\.[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]{2} (?=\" target)', 'http://domain.com.uy " target')
```

This gives me the "exact" output that I want. that is `domain.com.uy` but obviously this is just an example since `[a-z]{6}` just matches the previous 6 characters and this is not what I want.

I want it to return `domain.com.uy` so basically the instruction would be **match any character until "/" is encountered (backwards).**

Edit:

```
m =re.findall('\w+\.[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]{2} (?=\" target)', 'http://domain.com.uy " target')
```

Is very close to what I want but wont match "_" or "-".

For the sake of completeness I do **not** need the `http://`

I hope the question is clear enough, if I left anything open to interpretation please ask for any clarification needed!

Thank in advance!

Comment: See also: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) such as `(?<=//)`:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=//).+(?= \" target)', 
...           'http://domain.com.uy " target').group(0)
'domain.com.uy'
```

Note that this will match slashes within the url itself, if that's desired:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=//).+(?= \" target)',
...           'http://example.com/path/to/whatever " target').group(0)
'example.com/path/to/whatever'
```

If you just wanted the bare domain, without any path or query parameters, you could use `r'(?<=//)([^/]+)(/.*)?(?= \" target)'` and capture group 1:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=//)([^/]+)(/.*)?(?= \" target)',
...           'http://example.com/path/to/whatever " target').groups()
('example.com', '/path/to/whatever')
```

Comment: The first one is exactly what I want!! Thank you very much, I was clearly using a very strange approach! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

try this (maybe you need to escape `/` in Python):

```
/([^/]*)$
```

Comment: This will also catch the slash, which was unwanted. :>

Comment: Maybe I'm doning something stupid, I'm not really good with regex they take me a lot of time, you meant like this `m =re.findall('/([^/]*)$[a-z]\.[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]{2} (?=\" target)', 'http://domain.com.uy " target')
` because it is not working.

Comment: @Leif It won't catch slash, it wont work if there is no slash at all. I agree that you can just remove it.

Comment: @Trufa I don't know syntax of Python regex, but I gave you a whole regex, not an addition to yours :-) Do you want to get domain name? because everything from the end till slash in not the same thing.

Comment: @Thresh: Ohh sorry, I suck at reading regex it takes me an eternity, I'll try out yours now knowing it's not an extension. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: @Trufa If you want to get the domain, the easiest and best understandable is this: `//([^/]*)`. Only what will be inside braces will be caught: everything between `//` and first `/`.

Answer (score 1):

If regular expressions are not a requirement and you simply wish to extract the FQDN from the URL in Python. Use `urlparse` and `str.split()`:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://domain.com.uy " target'
>>> urlparse(url)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='domain.com.uy " target', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

This has broken up the URL into its component parts. We want `netloc`:

```
>>> urlparse(url).netloc
'domain.com.uy " target'
```

Split on whitespace:

```
>>> urlparse(url).netloc.split()
['domain.com.uy', '"', 'target']
```

Just the first part:

```
>>> urlparse(url).netloc.split()[0]
'domain.com.uy'
```

Comment: I'll give this a look, regex are definitely not requeried I just though it might be a good option in this case.

Comment: Whenever regexp and url are used in the same sentence it usually sounds like a bad idea. +1

Comment: Ask what you really want to know - not "how do I make technique X work to solve problem Y?", but "how do I solve problem Y?".

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
[^/]+(?= " target)
```

But be aware that http://domain.com/folder/site.php will not return the domain.
And remember to escape the regex properly in a string.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really good with regex, tehy take me a lot of time to understand you meant like this? `m =re.findall('[^/]+$[a-z]\.[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]{2} (?=\" target)', 'http://domain.com.uy " target')
` because its not working.

Comment: Sorry, a misunderstanding. Correcting this. You have to use my whole regex btw.